# How Convert array with keys to json

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array from my state collecting several elements

```
this.setState({
    [elem.module_id]: {
        element_id: elem.element_id,
        element_title: elem.element_title,
        value: e,
        module_id: elem.module_id,
        mandatory: elem.elementmand,
    },
});
```

When I print

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state));

{
  "1258": {
    "element_id": 3901,
    "element_title": "Write somethign Text",
    "value": "Cxcxcxcxcx",
    "module_id": 1258
  },
  "1284": {
    "element_id": 3927,
    "element_title": "wqqwqwwqwq",
    "value": "433434343",
    "module_id": 1284
  }
}
```

I would like to convert it to this format and remove the keys

> [   {
>       "element_id": 3901,
>       "element_title": "Write somethign Text",
>       "value": "Cxcxcxcxcx",
>       "module_id": 1258   },   {
>       "element_id": 3927,
>       "element_title": "wqqwqwwqwq",
>       "value": "433434343",
>       "module_id": 1284   } ]

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `Object.values(this.state)`

Answer (score 0):

This is what Object.values returns.

```js
const state = {
  "1258": {
    "element_id": 3901,
    "element_title": "Write somethign Text",
    "value": "Cxcxcxcxcx",
    "module_id": 1258
  },
  "1284": {
    "element_id": 3927,
    "element_title": "wqqwqwwqwq",
    "value": "433434343",
    "module_id": 1284
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.values(state)));
```